# How can I get the value of 2 series at the same time with React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I get the value of 2 series at the same time with React?
I need something like that

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

array.map(item1,item2=>(
   <div>
     <span>item1 - item2</div>
   </div>
))
```

Expected output:

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.from()` to create an array with half the length of the original array, and take the items from the original array:

```js
const Demo = ({ items = [] }) => (
  <div>
  {Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(items.length / 2) }, (_, i) => (
     <div>
      {items[i * 2]} - {items[i * 2 + 1]}
     </div>
  ))}
  </div>
)

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo items={array} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the array always has an even number of elements:

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

Array.from(Array(array.length / 2).keys())
  .map(i => {
    const item1 = array[i*2];
    const item2 = array[i*2 + 1];

    return (
      <div>
        <span>item1 - item2</div>
      </div>
    );
  )
```

There are many ways, but the basic trick is to iterate with steps of 2 elements. In this example, I'm iterating from 0 to the first half of the array *indexes*. If we multiply it by 2, we transform [0, 1, 2] to [0, 2, 4]. Then, add 1 for the second element.